# Batch convert multi page TIFFs to multi page or individual page PDFs on MAC

Tags: pdf, batch, conversion, jpeg, tiff

I have hundreds of Multi page TIFFs that I need to turn into individual image JPG files (file names not important).
Some had already been converted into multi page PDFs and I found a solution using automator to convert the multi page PDFs to individual JPG, but now I am stuck with the ones that were only in multi page TIFF format.
I can open each file in preview and then export as PDF and it will work, but I have HUNDREDS to do.  I tried opening them all in preview at once but that doesnt work. 
 I did about 40 and decided better to come back in hopes of a quicker solution.  Running Mac Sierra but have access to Windows 10 too.  Looking for free and simple solution please.

Comment: We are not a scripting service. Please share your research.

Comment: For some starting points you can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and a `FOR` loop and something like: `FOR %%A IN ("%TIFDir%\*.tiff") DO convert "%TIFDir%\%%~nxA" "%JPGDir%\%%~nA.jpg` to get all the TIFF images converted to JPG. For the conversion to each page being it's own separate file, maybe test with [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and look at the `cat` command but I'd have to put more thought into how to make it dynamically figure out how many pages each doc has, how to name the output so there's not overlap, etc.

Comment: BTW... I use Windows with these tools since you say you have Windows 10 so I'm not sure if they work on Mac machines or not but this is simple quick thoughts for starting points for you so get to work and start testing and [edit] your question with what you figure out and show this to get a more accurate answer and so people don't think you want them to build something for you from scratch... do your fair share of work for you stuff and [edit] your answer with what you tried and are having trouble with to get more help from others.